# Bash script for plotting with gnuplot

Tags: linux, bash, plot, gnuplot, ampl

Hy guys!
I have problems with writing bash script to run 50 times my script which generates data files and then plot it to file.
I wrote smth like this, but it doesnt work

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}
do
    ./ampl ampltst1 # generates different res.txt file each time
    /usr/bin/gnuplot <<\__EOF
    set xrange [-2:2]
    set yrange [-2:2]
    set term png
    set output "image-${i}.png"
    plot "res.txt" u 1:2 w lines, "res.txt" u 3:4 w lines, "res.txt" u 5:6 w li$
    pause -1
    __EOF
done
```

Please help me to fix this script!

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error message? Other observations.

Comment: why pause -1? it requires you to press Enter 50 times.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you have problems with indentation: `__EOF` must be without any leading spaces:

```
...
    /usr/bin/gnuplot <<\__EOF
    set xrange [-2:2]
    ...
__EOF
done
```

Also `\` symbol is not required.

Also content of HERE-IS-DOCUMENT will be indented. Is that OK for gnuplot?

If no, you must remove indentation:

```
for i in {1..50}
do
    ./ampl ampltst1 # generates different res.txt file each time
    /usr/bin/gnuplot <<__EOF
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set term png
set output "image-${i}.png"
plot "res.txt" u 1:2 w lines, "res.txt" u 3:4 w lines, "res.txt" u 5:6 w li$
pause -1
__EOF
done
```